# How can i get countries and states from JSON and populate it on Spinner

Tags: android, json, android-studio, spinner, adapter

I have the JSON format of countries and states, **how can i add countries in one `Spinner` and get corresponding state in another spinner**, my JSON format of counties and state is:

```
[
  {
    "Country": "Afghanistan",
    "State": [
        "Badakhshan",
        "Badgis",
        "Baglan",
        "Balkh",
        "Bamiyan",
        "Farah",
        "Faryab",
        "Gawr",
        "Gazni",
        "Herat",
        "Hilmand",
        "Jawzjan",
        "Kabul",
        "Kapisa",
        "Khawst",
        "Kunar",
        "Lagman",
        "Lawghar",
        "Nangarhar",
        "Nimruz",
        "Nuristan",
        "Paktika",
        "Paktiya",
        "Parwan",
        "Qandahar",
        "Qunduz",
        "Samangan",
        "Sar-e Pul",
        "Takhar",
        "Uruzgan",
        "Wardag",
        "Zabul"
    ]
},
{
    "Country": "Albania",
    "State": [
        "Badakhshan",
        "Badgis",
        "Baglan",
        "Balkh",
        "Bamiyan",
        "Farah",
        "Faryab",
        "Gawr",
        "Gazni",
        "Herat",
        "Hilmand",
        "Jawzjan",
        "Kabul",
        "Kapisa",
        "Khawst",
        "Kunar",
        "Lagman",
        "Lawghar",
        "Nangarhar",
        "Nimruz",
        "Nuristan",
        "Paktika",
        "Paktiya",
        "Parwan",
        "Qandahar",
        "Qunduz",
        "Samangan",
        "Sar-e Pul",
        "Takhar",
        "Uruzgan",
        "Wardag",
        "Zabul",
        "Berat",
        "Bulqize",
        "Delvine",
        "Devoll",
        "Dibre",
        "Durres",
        "Elbasan",
        "Fier",
        "Gjirokaster",
        "Gramsh",
        "Has",
        "Kavaje",
        "Kolonje",
        "Korce",
        "Kruje",
        "Kucove",
        "Kukes",
        "Kurbin",
        "Lezhe",
        "Librazhd",
        "Lushnje",
        "Mallakaster",
        "Malsi e Madhe",
        "Mat",
        "Mirdite",
        "Peqin",
        "Permet",
        "Pogradec",
        "Puke",
        "Sarande",
        "Shkoder",
        "Skrapar",
        "Tepelene",
        "Tirane",
        "Tropoje",
        "Vlore"
    ]
},
```

I search on many resources but i cant find proper way to do the above method. Everyone doing it on by adding the countries in custom array, please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: what's the problem with custom array?

Comment: first parse the json and add the parsed data into an array, then pass this array adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do following steps,

1. get data from json,
2. add array of country and add array state from json
3. now, `OnItemSelected` of country position bind state accordingly

EX:

```
//Setting Adapter for country spinner 

        if (stateDataList != null && stateDataList.size() > 0) {
                StateSpinnerAdapter StateAdapter = new StateSpinnerAdapter(this, stateDataList);
                SpinState.setAdapter(StateAdapter);
            }
```

than `setOnItemSelectedListener` country spinner to get states

```
private ArrayList<ModelStateDetails> stateDataList;

        SpinState.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                if (position > 0) {
                    new LongOperation().execute("" + position);
                    Log.e(5, "state code", "-->>" + position);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Vanghela thanks for your resonance, let me try your idea,

Comment: yes i got it, but i follow little bit different code.. thank you

Comment: did you got it?@Sam

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented same for finding locale in provience. This example uses 3 spinner.you can use according to your need.

```
 //set onItemSelected Listener


           spinProvince.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String province = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    if(province.matches("Eastern Cape")){
                        spinPro = 1;
                        populateDist();
                    }
                    else if(province.matches("Free State")){
                        spinPro = 2;
                        populateDist();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    Toast.makeText(Reg_Prop.this, "Please select the Province where the Property is located", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            spinDistrict.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String spinDist = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    if(spinDist.matches("Buffalo City") && spinPro == 1){
                        dist = 1;
                        populateLocal();
                    }
                    else if(spinDist.matches("Nelson Mandela Bay") && spinPro == 1){
                        dist = 2;
                        populateLocal();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

   /* Functions to populate the spinners*/

        void populateDist(){
            //Eatern Cape
            if(spinPro == 1){
                String [] ec = {"Select District/Metro *", "Buffalo City", "Nelson Mandela Bay",
                        "Alfred Nzo District", "Amathole District", "Chris Hani District",
                        "Joe Gqabi District", "OR Tambo District", "Cacadu District"};

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ec);
                spinDistrict.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            //Free State
            else if(spinPro == 2){
                String [] fs = {"Select District/Metro *", "Mangaung Metropolitan", "Fezile Dabi District",
                        "Lejweleputswa District", "Thabo Mofutsanyana District", "Xhariep District"};

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fs);
                spinDistrict.setAdapter(adapter2);
            }

        }

        void populateLocal(){
            //Baffalo City
            if(dist == 1){
                String [] bc = {"Buffalo City"};

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapterL1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, bc);
                spinLocal.setAdapter(adapterL1);
            }
            //Nelson Mandela Bay
            else if(dist == 2){
                String [] nmb = {"Nelson Mandela Bay"};

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapterL2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nmb);
                spinLocal.setAdapter(adapterL2);
            }

        }
```

Comment: also add steps/description when posting answers.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek Mishra but i added all the countries (246) in my json so my code will getting longer when i do the above method,