# a simple way to declare a spinner with array

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner, android-spinner

I want to make some dynamically added `Spinner` on android. When First `Spinner` is selected, the second spinner will appear. I want to create all the `Spinner` programatically.

Here's what I've done so far.

```
public class MainActivity  extends Activity {

    Spinner spnKolom[]; // I declare an array of Spinner

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

So I tried creating the Spinners like this.

```
final DataHelper db = new DataHelper(getApplicationContext());
final List<String> labelKolom = db.getKolom();

for (int itung=0;itung<labelKolom.size();itung++){
    spnKolom[itung] = new Spinner(this);
}
```

What is the right way to do this?

**Edit**

My problem is on declaring a spinner with array. In my expetation, I want to declare one Spinner with array to make many spinner, so I can use it to create a New Spinner when First spinner is selected.

Comment: Is your total number of spinners are fixed or not ? Means how many spinners are you want to create dynamically ?

Comment: something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/39405348/2826147

Comment: @Vickyexpert total spinner following the number of columns in my database. so the number of spinners are not fixed.

Comment: @AmitVaghela no, I can't find my answer on [This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405148/how-can-i-get-countries-and-states-from-json-and-populate-it-on-spinner/39405348#39405348)

Comment: @D.AjiPratama maybe you need to read more carefully

Comment: in that link, there is **setOnItemSelectedListener()**, in that on **onItemSelected()** show or create another spinner.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice My problem is on declaring a spinner with array. In my expetation, I want to declare one Spinner with array to make many spinner, so I can use it to create a New Spinner when First spinner is selected.

Comment: @D.AjiPratama Check my Answer, hope it will help you

Comment: @AmitVaghela thanks for your explanation, I can use it later. but I'm still not coding on there phase.

Comment: that is what your question is about "When First Spinner is selected, the second spinner will appear"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding of your requirement I have done below coding, so please check it, hope it will help you.

**First Implement Listner in your Activity**

```
    public class MainActivity  extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

**Now Your XML file should look like below**

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_Layout"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scMainView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llSpinnerSection"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Now in your main activity declare your layout as below**

```
   LinearLayout  mainSpinnerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSpinnerSection);
```

**Now Create One Method For Getting Data And Set Spinner**

```
   public void createSpinners()
   {

      final DataHelper db = new DataHelper(getApplicationContext());
      final List<String> labelKolom = db.getKolom();

      spnKolom = new Spinner[labelKolom.size()];

      for (int itung=0;itung<labelKolom.size();itung++)
      {
           spnKolom[itung] = new Spinner(this);
           spnKolom[itung].setTag(itung);

           ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelKolom);
           spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          spnKolom[itung].setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
          spnKolom[itung].setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

          if(itung == 0)
          {
             spnKolom[itung].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
          else
          {
             spnKolom[itung].setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }

          mainSpinnerLayout.addView(spnKolom[itung]);
     }
}
```

**And Finally Implement Methods For Spinner To Show Next Spinner on Item Selection**

```
//Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id) {

    if(position < spnKolom.length - 1)
    {
        spnKolom[position + 1].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

**Hope this will work for you**

Comment: Yeah, that is what I want. :D

Answer (score 1):

Add adapter to spinner like

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // Visible the second spinner and set it data on the basis of selection
      showDataOfSecondSpinnerOnBasisOfSelection(spinnerArray[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably worked. I have worked with TextView array. I have not used Spinner.
**But your spinner array should have a size.**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

This is how you **might** want to add an spinner to the UI.